# Cell Click in tableview doesn't navigate to new controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tableview in my application and I want to push a new view controller on cell click of tableview but it is not working.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let section = indexPath.section
    let controller : ProductInfoViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProductInfoViewController") as! ProductInfoViewController
    controller.product = TableData[section]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
     print("clicked section : \(section)")
   // print(TableData[row])
}
```

Does any one have idea what mistake I am doing here? I have proper view controller with ID in storyboard. No error is coming in console as well.

Comment: table,table cell user interface is true ... check

Comment: are you embed the viewcontroller in navigation controller

Comment: It is separate view controller. How to check cell user interface true herE?

Comment: is `self.navigationController` `nil`?

Comment: Yes self.navigationController is coming nil

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  method in insert         cell.userInteractionEnabled=true

Comment: Click event is working fine but it is not pushing the new controller so I thing cell.userInteractionEnabled is already true.

Comment: can you show your storboard scene once'

Comment: are you returning number of Sections in table view or number of rows in section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your navigationController is nil then you don't have any navigation stack to push viewcontroller on.It looks you are using storyboard so embed this controller to navigationcontroller.for this select this view controller in storyboard click "Editor" in top menu goto "Embed in" and select navigationcontroller...Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Storyboard Name and check you will set the Storyboard ID and my code is below,

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayViewController") as! PlayViewController
        controller.titleLabel = (myArrayOfDict[indexpath.section].valueForKey("Title") as? String)!

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let section = indexPath.section
    let controller : ProductInfoViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProductInfoViewController") as! ProductInfoViewController
    controller.product = TableData[section]

    // execute in main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }


     print("clicked section : \(section)")
   // print(TableData[row])
}
```

Comment: It is not working. My self.navigationcontroller is nil .

Answer (score 0):

Create a swift file (SecondViewController.swift) for the second view controller and in the appropriate function type this:

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController

self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `self.navigationController` is coming nil, means your view controller is not added to the navigation stack.. So you have to write code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.viewController = ViewController()
    self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.viewController)
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController!
    self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = true
    return true
}
```

try this may be it will help you:-

Comment: Could you please give me swift code rather than objective C

Comment: What is your viewcontroller here?

Comment: I have a loginView Controller and then mainViewController. I am able to see the loginviewcontroller and Mainviewcontroller. Once I push any controller from MainViewController, it is not pushing and giving error. I just hiddn the NavigationBar in Controller so why it is coming nil after 2 controller.

Comment: firstly tell me that have you write that code which i have given you wrote on your app.m and in didfonishlaunchwithoptions